# What does apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style do?

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari

What does

```html
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
```

do -- can someone explain with an example?

I found [this line](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html) in the official Safari Developer Library

> This meta tag has no effect unless you
>   first specify full-screen mode as
>   described in “url.”

But which url?

What is the benefit of this meta tag?

Comment: Just a comment on #1. As long as you have set the apples iphone/ipad metatags in the next page you load, it will continue to hide the address bar and navigation buttons. My problem is that setting: `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />` has no effect at all. I would prefer if there was a way to hide the status bar totally. I'll continue doing research on that tomorrow. :-)

Comment: 'I would prefer if there was a way to hide the status bar totally' Can this be done?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

First, the `apple-mobile-web-app-capable` hint has to be set for that to even work. This hint causes a web application to run in full-screen mode: it removes the address bar and navigation buttons you get by default in Mobile Safari. The removed areas are highlighted in red here:

[image: apple mobile web app capable]

So, once an app is in full-screen mode (i.e. the user has added the website to their home page), you can also control the colour of the remaining thin status bar at the top of the page with `apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style`, highlighted in red here:

[image: apple mobile web app status bar style]

Per the docs:

> If content is set to `default`, the status bar appears normal. If set to `black`, the status bar has a black background. If set to `black-translucent`, the status bar is black and translucent. If set to default or black, the web content is displayed below the status bar. If set to `black-translucent`, the web content is displayed on the entire screen, partially obscured by the status bar.

A couple of caveats:

1. This only works on the *first* page you load; any navigation away to another page will make the address bar and navigation buttons reappear. So if you want this to work, you have to build a single page website (for multiple 'pages' consider an Ajax page loading approach such as that used in the jQuery Mobile framework).
2. This only works when you arrive at the web page *via an application shortcut icon;* if you navigate to the website directly from within Mobile Safari it has no effect.

Comment: So it only works when user will open the website from desktop shortcut. it will not effective when user will open the website first time by typing the url in address bar, am i right?

Comment: then it's only should be used with web-app because in website if user want to bookmark any inner page it would not be possible because bottom bar will not come.

Answer (score 0):

It changes the top bar w/ the banner and carrier on it and makes it a translucent black.